# react-native : picking random image using Math.floor

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to pick random image using `Math.floor`. I want to select image between 20 images that I assigned.

I have 20 images:

```
const randomImages = [
    require('../Components/Assets/blind1.png'),
    require('../Components/Assets/blind2.png'),
    require('../Components/Assets/blind3.png'),
    ... up to 20
];
```

Then, I try to select random image like this:

```
 selectedRandomImage(){
    const randomImage = randomImages[Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1)]
    console.log(randomImage,'randomImage')
    return(
      <View>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 56, height: 56 }}
          source={randomImage} />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

**My question:** I get random Image using the code above but when I `console.log(randomImage,'randomImage')`

I get numbers over 20. Why is this? isn't it supposed to be under 20?.

When the number is over 20 I still get the random image though.

Comment: indexes start at 0.

Comment: I know that. console.log some times show over 30.

Comment: Over 30 shouldnt happen, but you generate numbers 0-20, and only have 20 images in your array.

Comment: There's no way the posted code can go above 19

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()`  generate number between 0 to 1 then
`Math.random() * 19`  generate number between 0 to 19 and
`(Math.random() * 19) + 1`  produce number between 1 to 20 but your array has 19 index and randomImages[20] return undefined

Answer (score 0):

`randomImage` variable have some random image path from `randomImages` array.

`require("path to image")` returns the number mapped to image. 
react native maps unique numbers to static images and that's why when you try to log, it is giving number over 20.

But, if you try to log `Math.floor((Math.random() * 19) + 1)` value, it will be below 20.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const imageCollection =
    [
      require('App/assets/images/doe1.jpg'),
      require('App/assets/images/doe2.jpg'),
      require('App/assets/images/doe3.jpg'),
      require('App/assets/images/doe4.jpg'),
      require('App/assets/images/John-Doe.jpg'),
      require('App/assets/images/John-Doe.jpg'),
    ];

    const getRandomImage = () => 
      imageCollection[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageCollection.length)];
```

Would be a better approach as the function is aware of the length of the images array and will update accordingly.